# How many days must a CPAP be stopped before a sleep endoscopy?

Tags: sleep, sleep-apnea, endoscopy

I understand that, for a sleep endoscopy done in a patient who has sleep apnea for a few (three) years, the use of CPAP must be stopped before the endoscopy, as CPAP has à residual effect for some days depending on the patient, 3, 5, 7 or 10 days.

But ideally speaking, how long before the endoscopy must the use of CPAP be stopped? Are three days enough to get rid of the residual effect?

Thank you and kind regards.